# Excel table to JSON file using vba

Tags: json, vba

I am trying to export excel rows to a json file but it seems like I'm running issue when it comes to one particular line of code.
Here's what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Draft Log")
If ws Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub 'possible way of handing no worksheet was set
End If

Dim excelRange As Range
Dim jsonItems As New Collection
Dim jsonDictionary As New Dictionary
Dim jsonFileObject As New FileSystemObject
Dim jsonFileExport As TextStream
Dim i As Long
Dim cell As Variant

Set excelRange = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

For i = 2 To excelRange.Rows.Count
    jsonDictionary("Institution-id") = Cells(i, 1)
    jsonDictionary("record-id") = Cells(i, 2)
    jsonDictionary("anonymous") = Cells(i, 3)


    jsonItems.Add jsonDictionary
    Set jsonDictionary = Nothing
Next i

'change the path below to save where you desire
Set jsonFileExport = jsonFileObject.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\username\Desktop\jsonExample.json", False)
jsonFileExport.WriteLine (JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonItems, Whitespace:=3))


End Sub
```

This line is where it goes wrong and can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
jsonFileExport.WriteLine (JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(jsonItems, Whitespace:=3))
```

Comment: "where it goes wrong " - what exactly goes wrong?  Are you getting an error message?  If Yes, what message?

Comment: That code works fine for me.

Comment: I'm hitting a runtime error  '424' stating that an object is required and the json file it saves is empty.

Comment: Maybe be a bit more explicit when setting the range: `Set excelRange = ws.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion`  Since it worked for me, it may be related to the input range/data you're using.